# How to recover Mesos executor after Mesos framework failure?

Tags: mesos

My scenario is that a framework is running on server A. It has an executor on server B running a task (a long running web service with a long initialization time). Server A is shutdown. The framework is then restarted somewhere else in the cluster.

Currently, after the restart the new framework registers a new executor which runs a new task. After some time, the Mesos master deactivates the old and no-longer-running framework which in turn kills the old but still-running executor and its task.

I would like the new framework to re-register the old executor rather than register a new one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This on the Mesos forum answers my question:

http://www.mail-archive.com/user%40mesos.apache.org/msg00069.html

Included here for reference:

> > (1) One thing particular I found unexpected is that the executors are 
> >     shutdown if the scheduler is shutdown. Is there a way to keep executors/tasks 
> >     running when the scheduler is down? I would imagine when the scheduler comes 
> >     back, it could reestablish the state somehow and keep going without 
> >     interrupting the running tasks. Is this a use case that mesos is designed for?
>
> You can use FrameworkInfo.failover_timeout to tell Mesos how long to wait for  the framework to re-register before it cleans up the
>   framework's executors and  tasks.
>
> Also, note that for this to work the framework has to persist its
>   frameworkId  when it first registers with the master.  When the
>   framework comes back up it  needs to reconnect by setting
>   FrameworkInfo.framework_id = persisted id.